# Try to call server action in client component

Tags: next.js, server-action

I'm trying to use the server actions in the client component
but it shows error like - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workers')

```
in form.jsx

'use client';

import {uploadFile} from "@/app/lib/File/actions";

<form action={uploadFile(formData)}>
  <TextField label="Title" name={"title"} id={"title"} variant="outlined" fullWidth required />
  <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
</form>
```

```
in action.js

"use server";

export const uploadFile = async (formData) => {
    const title = formData.get('title');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly calling the method inside the action callback, instead you should be using a callback so the function does not get called on each render.

```
"use client";

import { useCallback } from "react";
import { uploadFile } from "@/app/lib/File/actions";

export default function MyClientComponent() {
  const onSubmit = useCallback(async (formData) => {
    const result = await uploadFile(formData);
    // do something with result
  }, []);

  return (
    <form action={onSubmit}>
      <TextField
        label="Title"
        name={"title"}
        id={"title"}
        variant="outlined"
        fullWidth
        required
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This also allows you to get a result from the `uploadFile` server action update your UI accordingly.

Comment: It's working, Thanks.